# multiple text fields in a row with padding

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to create a row with multiple texts filed side by side. adding text fileds inside row widget caused errors so I google the problem and found a solution which uses Flexible widget for putting text fields inside a row and It worked perfectly, however when I tried to add padding to text filed in order to have vision of multiple texts filed, it won't work here is my code:

```
new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Flexible(
          child: new TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)
              )
          ),
        ),
        new Flexible(
          child: new TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)
              )
          ),
        ),
        new Flexible(
          child: new TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)
              )
          ),
        ),
      ],
),
```

I want to have something like picutre bellow:
[image]

how can I add some padding to text filed. 
And I wonder is there any way that I achieve this with one text filed?

Comment: perhaps looks at underline Input Border?
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/UnderlineInputBorder-class.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could add `SizedBox` in between. The `TextField` tries to get the maximum size when you use the `Flexible` so no space is left in the middle, even if you use `spaceBetween`.

```
new Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    new Flexible(
      child: new TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)
          )
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
    new Flexible(
      child: new TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)
          )
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
    new Flexible(
      child: new TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)
          )
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

You could also use `Padding` around the `TextField`.

```
new Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    new Flexible(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)
            )
        ),
      ),
    ),
    new Flexible(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)
            )
        ),
      ),
    ),
    new Flexible(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)
            )
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```